# Html.DropDownList setting selected Item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I set selected Item of Html.DropDownList to Request.QueryString["JobType"]

```
<td class="data"><%= Html.DropDownList("MaintJobTypes")%>
```

some thing to:

```
<td class="data"><%= Html.DropDownList("MaintJobTypes").selectedItem = Request.QueryString["JobType"]%>
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624828/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-selectedvalue), it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set `ViewData["MaintJobTypes"]` equal to the value of the item you want to select, `Html.DropDownList` will pick that up and set the selected value.  You can also use a property on `Model` as long as the name of the drop down list matches the model property.

Alternatively you can use the `SelectList` helper which provides a list of items and the selected one.

More examples and details available here:

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/10/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx