# My dropdownlist is not selecting an item as expected (MVC 1)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

OK so I have 2 pages where this kind of behaviour is implemented.  It works on one but doesn't work in another and I have no idea why.  Despite the data containing a list of selectitems and one of them is selected the dropdown list is not displaying this selection (ie. it resets to the blank item).

I don't know how to further debug this.

In my page:

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("CampusId", ViewData.Model.Campuses, new { @class = "large search_box" })%>
```

In my controller.

```
Campuses = AdminRepository
          .ListAll<Campus>(a => a.Description)
          .ToSelectListItem<Campus>(a => a.CampusId, a => a.Description, criteria.CampusId, true);
```

I can see that campuses does have the correct list item marked as selected - so why when it is displayed on the page is it no longer marked as selected?! I can't see anything else obviously modifying the list.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so in trying different google search terms I came across this:
[ASP.NET MVC Html.DropDownList SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624828/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-selectedvalue)

The issue was my drop down list had the same name as in the model.  So I changed my html to be

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("CampusIdDD", ViewData.Model.Campuses, new { @class = "large search_box" })%>
```

So problem solved!!!  Hopefully we'll be able to upgrade from MVC 1 !!

Answer (score 1):

Model.Campuses
Model.CampusId
<%= Html.Hidden("CampusId") %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("CampusId", ViewData.Model.Campuses, new { @class = "large search_box" })%>