# SelectList not setting Selected Value when passing in SelectItems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

```
foreach (Person person in personList) {                               
  SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
  item.Value = person.Id;
  item.Text = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;                    
  items.Add(item);
}

ViewData["personSelectList"] = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", 4);

<%=Html.DropDownList("personId", ViewData["personSelectList"] as SelectList)%>
```

This code is not setting the person with Id = 4 as the selected item, but rather always picking the first item in the list as the selected item.

What step am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Html.DropDownList SelectedValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624828/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-selectedvalue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `Selected` property on the item itself? e.g.

```
foreach (Person person in personList)
{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = person.Id,
        Text = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
        Selected = person.Id == 4
    });
}
```

**Update**

I think you need to pass in the selected value through to the view and handle it in there instead:

```
ViewData["personSelectList"] = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
ViewData["personId"] = 4;
```

View

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("personId", ViewData["personSelectList"] as SelectList) %>
```

Comment: Tried this... doesn't work. Very frustrating, because it should definitely be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (Person person in personList)
{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = person.Id,
        Text = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName,
        Selected = person.Id == 4
    });
}

ViewData["personSelectList"] = items
```

then view

```
@Html.DropDownList("holdPersonSelectList", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["personSelectList")
```

then back to controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string holdPersonSelectList)
```

edit:
holdPersonSelectList in the controller will hold a string value of the Value of the selected Item.
So, If it's an id field, just parse to int.

If you're looking to set a value, I would pass in a different piece of viewdata holding that number, and set it using jquery // javascript.

```
$('holdPersonSelectList').val('4');
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectListItem.Value` is a `string` but you're passing `4` - which is an integer.  Try passing `"4"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote test using MVC3 and it works without problem:

```
@{
var items = new[]
                {
                    new Test {Id = 1, Name = "Jhon"}, 
                    new Test {Id = 2, Name = "Scott"}
                };

var selectList = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name", 2);
var selectEnumerable = items.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                             {
                                                 Selected = x.Id == 2,
                                                 Text = x.Name,
                                                 Value = x.Id.ToString()
                                             });
}

@Html.DropDownList("name", selectList)
@Html.DropDownList("name2", selectEnumerable)
```

On both DropDownLists selected value is Scott, so it does select second item as written in code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was different. I had to change `SelectList` to `MultiSelectList`

So, instead of doing the foreach, I do something like

```
int[] personListSelected= personList.Select(p=>(int)p.idPerson).ToArray();

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> personList = new MultiSelectList(personList, "idPerson", "namePerson",personListSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you can do the following;

```cs
ViewData["personSelectList"] = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == 4).id);
```

or better yet,

```cs
int SelectedID = 4;
ViewData["personSelectList"] = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == SelectedID).id);
```